# Change index() value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<ul>
  <li id="step1">Item1<a id="button1">Move down</a></li>
  <li id="step2">Item2<a id="butto2">Move down</a></li>
  <li id="step3">Item3<a id="button3">Move down</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to set a click() event that will move the li element at the place of the next one.

I can retrieve an item's index with jQuery by doing this:

```
$("li#step1").index()
```

I'd like to be able to increment it or decrement it (2 by 2). I am trying to change it like this:

```
$("li#etape1").index($("li#etape1").index() + 2)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working (whenever I do this in Chrome's console, I get -1).
How could I do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `$(selector).index()` / `$.index('selector')` / `$(parent).index('child')` will return element index in dom, there is no setter for that

Comment: you cannot change the index of an element. but can change the index by positioning the element according to the parent.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: The provided HTML is invalid. Because `a` cannot be directly nested under `ul`.

Comment: @GrahamSlick you can try my answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('li').click(function(){
var index= $(this).index();
$(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find("li").eq(index+1));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ze471vun/

or:

```
$('li').click(function(){
var index= $(this).index();
$(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
});
```

Comment: ID can only be unique in DOM, so there will be no element at any other position with selector `li#step820`

Comment: The eq() function is rather irrelevant in this case. You could do the same with square brackets and the code will be more readable. The insertAfter() function is the main method at work here.

Comment: This answers the "increment" portion of the issue, but there are potential bugs with extrapolating to other cases. "Decrement" could work by changing **both** `insertAfter()` to `insertBefore()` **and** `+1` to `-1` or `next()` to `prev()`.

Answer (score 1):

To down your `li` by 2 posiition, try the following code snippets, by using `index()`

**Code snippets:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var presentLi = $(this).closest("li"),
    targetLi = presentLi.closest("ul").children(":eq(" + (presentLi.index() + 2) + ")");
    targetLi.after(presentLi);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="step1">Item1 <a id="button1" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step2">Item2 <a id="button2" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step3">Item3 <a id="button3" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step4">Item4 <a id="button4" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step5">Item5 <a id="button5" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step6">Item6 <a id="button6" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step7">Item7 <a id="button7" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
  <li id="step8">Item8 <a id="button8" href="#">Move down</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if this is not your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot change index numbers directly.**  Moreover, moving an element in front of the next element in line does not increase the index number by 2.

The index number of an element represents its position in the array in the same way drivers have positions in a race. When one driver takes over another he takes his place, and the slower driver's position drops. Just the same, the very act of moving one element of an array forward moves the other one back (the total number of elements is preserved). No two elements can share an index, and no element can have an index greater than the total count of elements in an array. (more precisely, it's *greater or equal* because indices start at zero).

**You can, however, manipulate the ordering of elements.** An easy way to do so with jQuery would be the [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) functions. Alternatively, the *.insertBefore()* and *.insertAfter()* functions provide the same functionality, but are often more readable and intuitive.

A function that moves an element after its immediate sibling could then look like this:

```
function moveElementDown(elementSelector){
     var element = $(elementSelector);
     element.insertAfter(element.next());
}
```

If you want to have another function to move an element back, you can do so like this:

```
function moveElementUp(elementSelector){
     var element = $(elementSelector);
     element.insertBefore(element.prev());
}
```

And if you really need to move an element a certain number of spaces, a generalized function like this would do:

```
function moveElement(elementSelector, numOfSpaces){
     if(numOfSpaces=== 0)
         return;
     var element = $(elementSelector);
     var siblings = element.parent().children();
     var targetIndex = Math.max(0,Math.min(element.index() + numOfSpaces, siblings.length-1));

     if(targetIndex === element.index())
         return;
     if(targetIndex === 0)
         element.parent().prepend(element);
     else if(targetIndex === siblings.length-1)
         element.parent().append(element);
     else if (numOfSpaces> 0)
         element.insertBefore(siblings[targetIndex+1]);
     else
         element.insertAfter(siblings[targetIndex-1]);
}
```