# How to move div is below to top in another div?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

i have block sample

```html
 <div class="e">
  <div class="a" >
    1111
  </div>
  <div class="b" >
    22222
  </div>
  <div class="b" >
    3333
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="d" >
    14141414
</div>
```

How to resulte move class d to seconde after class a?

```
1111
14141414
22222
3333
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit quick and dirty, but you could maybe just jquery to achieve what your looking for.

I threw this together in a couple minutes, so there may be a better way to do this.

Basically you insert the other item and then remove the last element.

```
$("#content .d").insertBefore( $("#content .b") );
$("#content .d").last().remove();
```

Heres a quick example
https://jsfiddle.net/m9k3rpo7/1/

Its also worth taking a look at this

[Change index() value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196730/change-index-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

A hack that will only work for this particular case:

```css
body  {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.e {
  display:contents;
}

.a,.d {
 order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="e">
  <div class="a" >
    1111
  </div>
  <div class="b" >
    22222
  </div>
  <div class="b" >
    3333
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="d" >
    14141414
</div>
```